# Replace words keeping original case

Tags: vba, ms-word, case-sensitive

I am making a program that replaces words in an MS Word document. I want to keep the original case of the words.

Let's say, there's an expression: "Broken Glass". I want to modify it to "Cristal Roto".

I have two textboxes, Input and Output.
Input is where the term to replace goes, and output is the word with which the input term will be replaced.

For this example, I would put "Broken Glass" in the (Input) textbox, and "Cristal Roto" in the (Output) textbox.

The result in the Word document will be "Cristal roto". The second word's first letter gets lowercased.

```vb
Dim rng As Word.Range
rng = objWordS.ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Execute(FindText:=Input.Text, _
          ReplaceWith:=Output.Text, _
          MatchWholeWord:=True, _
          Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    End With
```

I only care about the original case of the first letter of each word.

**EDIT**
The reason "Broken Glass" ended up "Cristal roto" was that I missed adding this:

```
.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
```

Which I added just between `.ClearFormatting` and `.Execute`.

Now the text in the Word File is replaced with the case I use in the Output textbox.
Still, I would like to know if there is a way to detect the case of the original word in the Word File, to automatically adapt the Output Textbox's text without using Proper Case. So:
To Replace: "Broken Glass" - Replace text: "cristal roto" - Desired result: "Cristal Roto".

Comment: Is the same every time? I mean do you need all the words to be capitalized individually?

Comment: You might have to manually parse the text that's returned and then replace the capitalisation.

Comment: @3vts I mainly want it to stop converting the second word's first character to lowcase when I replace an expression. Say, "Dark Room" to "Habitación Oscura", not "Habitación oscura", which is what I'm getting now when replacing. You can reach this goal changing the "Replacewith:=Output.Text" for "Replacewith:=ProperSizeWord" with this code added to textbox modified text:
        Dim ProperSizeWords As String
        ProperSizeWords = StrConv(Output.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
But like this, you'd have to always turn it off / switch to other method if you want to replace with lowercase etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing `Output.Text` to `ProperCase` while executing the search. Something like this should work:

`ReplaceWith:=StrConv(Output.Text, vbProperCase)`

Shorter and cleaner. But you still have to use `ProperCase`,  don't know if this fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I wanted like this:

```
Dim rng As Word.Range
        rng = objWordS.ActiveDocument.Content
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting()
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting()
            .Execute(FindText:=InputText)
            If rng.Text = rng.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + rng.Text.Substring(1) Then
                .Execute(ReplaceWith:=Output.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + Output.Text.Substring(1).ToLower, _
                         MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                         Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
            End If
            If rng.Text = rng.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + rng.Text.Substring(1) Then
                .Execute(ReplaceWith:=Output.Text, _
                         MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                         Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
            End If
        End With
```

This way, I don't have to manually change the casing every single time, what this will do is replace the word based on if its first character is an Uppercase or a Lowercase letter. In case it's an uppercase, the text will be replaced with the casing used in Output (ex. BroKeN WindoW).

If it's a lowercase, then it will replace the words lowercasing the content of output (ex. broken window). With this method, I may be able to implement new conditions in the future, like "If first word's first letter is uppercase, but second word's first letter is lowercase, then...". I hope this will be useful for someone else too.

Actually, I may even implement a condition with Proper Casing to achieve what I asked under EDIT in the main question.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: With your code it would always capitalize first letters, and for the purpose I'm using it I only need to do that sometimes, I just forgot to mention that on the main post! But I will also use the example you posted, say for smg like:
    If rng.Text = StrConv(rng.Text, vbProperCase) Then .Execute(ReplaceWith:=StrConv(Output.Text, vbProperCase), _
Thanks for answering and for your time!